# Using a batch file to start pm2 when windows starts?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pm2

I can't get [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to start my apps on Windows start. I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and `pm2 2.4.2`.

I have a [pm2 process file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) in JSON format which I use to start all my apps.

**c:\pm2\process.json**

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name" : "my-app",
      "script" : "c:\\node\\myapp\index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a batch file which uses the JSON file:

**c:\pm2\pm2-startup.bat**

```
@echo off

set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set PM2_HOME=C:\etc\.pm2
setx /M PM2_HOME C:\etc\.pm2

cd C:\pm2 & pm2 start process.json
```

I have a Windows task scheduled to run the batch file:

- Trigger: **At startup**
- Run under: **An administrator account**
- Run whether user is logged in or not: **Yes**
- Run with highest privileges: **Yes**
- Action: **Start a program**

  - Script: **C:\pm2\pm2-startup.bat**
  - Start in: **C:\pm2**

If I run the batch file manually (double clicking it), it works. If I run the scheduled task manually (right-click, run), it works.

When I restart the server and check the scheduled task, it has run, no errors, however the apps are not running. Doing `pm2 list` shows no apps in the table.

**I don't want to use** [pm2-windows-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service) because I don't want to run pm2 as a service (tried it and it was flaky).

**I don't want to use** [pm2-windows-startup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-startup) either as it doesn't seem to work with a [pm2 process file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/), it just tries to remember what was running before.

**I do want to use** a plain batch file on startup.

What am I doing wrong with the batch file..? Why does the scheduled task run ok, but the pm2 list is empty..?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but I'll leave an answer for future searches.

You can put a shortcut to the .bat file in the Windows Startup folder.

Assuming the PM2 cmd is in path, your bat file could look like this.

```
@echo off

SET PM2_HOME=C:\Users\pstart\.pm2

pm2 start C:\path\to\run.js
```

That'll start PM2 and run the program. Now you just take the bat file and save it somewhere and create a shortcut in the Windows Startup folder by clicking the Start button -> Run -> shell:startup and pasting it in there.

Answer (score 0):

In your "Action: Start a program" you should capture the output of the batch file for see what is going on.

Add to the action "Add arguments".
something like that: `> C:\temp\pm2_batch_log.txt 2>&1`

Also, it is doable to configure using windows service.
Here is my working [example](https://github.com/hagaigold/WinPM2).