# Unable to start PM2 batch file from Windows Task Scheduler on startup running a different user

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, pm2

I cannot run [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) successfully on Windows startup using the Task Scheduler in the following cases:

- Run the program under a different user account with Admin privileges.  The task scheduler output the task runs successfully but the program is not running when querying PM2 status.
- Run the program from the task scheduler using my own username account (with Admin privileges) and signoff even if the parameter "Run whether user is logged in or not" is turned on.

I've found a similar post related to my issue:  [Using a batch file to start pm2 when windows starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929125/using-a-batch-file-to-start-pm2-when-windows-starts)

My configurations files are:

**ecosystem.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'OrgChartJS',
    script: 'D:/wwwnodes/node_modules/@balkangraph/export-service/app.js',

    // Options reference: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }]
};
```

**PM2Startup.bat**

```
@echo off
SET PM2_HOME=D:\scripts\pm2
SETX /M PM2_HOME %PM2_HOME%

CD %PM2_HOME%
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env development
```

My Windows task is scheduled to run the PM2Startup,bat as follow:

- At startup
- Run under MyUsername (In group Administrators)
- Run whether the user is logged in or not.
- Run with highest privileges

I'm running Windows Server 2016 Standard, PM2 V4.2.3 and Node V12.13.1.

How could I make this work whether I'm logged in or not and whoever (with Admin privileges) is assigned to run the task in the scheduler ?

Comment: Programs not run as user when logged in are invisible.

Comment: It should be `CD /D "%PM2_HOME%"`. However, it would be more robust to modify the order. 1st `CD /D "D:\scripts\pm2" 2>NUL||Exit /B` 2nd `SetX PM2_HOME "%CD%" /M`. Then you shouln't need to define `%PM2_HOME%` for the running script, just use `%CD%`, if needed, instead.

Comment: I've tried @Compo suggestions without any success.